# WhatsApp : Stop auto download of voice messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need to stop auto downloading of voice messages in WhatsApp since it's wasting a lot of my mobile data.

When I go to `Settings > Chat Settings > Media Auto Download`, it shows a note `Voice messages are always downloaded automatically for the best communication experience.`

Is there any other way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict background data by going to android settings > data usage > wifi > whatsapp and in the bottom you will see "restric app background data" just activate that and it will stop downloading in the background and it will somewhat solve your problem

Comment: It didnt work for me I tried I offend my background data of the WhatsApp but I tried it's still downloading I don't know why